# Android - Application onCreate method - when exporting ContentProvider

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, dagger-2

I am looking to share my ContentProvider with other apps. The Contentprovider is `NOT` a DB based provider, its makes some `Http` calls to provide the data. 
Now in order to make these http calls, I am setting up all my services under the Application's `onCreate()` method as they are .

My question is knowing the fact that a ContentProviders `onCreate()` can be called before the `Application` onCreate().

Can I safely assume, even when I share this contentProvider externally, my `Application onCreate()` is guaranteed to be called and I can rely on it to provide the required dependencies.

The background to this is I am using Dagger2 to inject these services in my ContentProvider, I can always lazy load, but the Application onCreate() needs to be called sometime for this to work ?

Comment: No its not guaranteed. Why do you need the Application class for this? Just get an instance of the dagger component in the `onCreate()` of the ContentProvider, and inject there?  As a LAST resort, in the Application class you can override `protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)` - however in this hook `getApplicationContext()` will return null.

Comment: Thanks, when you mention `attachBaseContext` if App's onCreate is not guaranteed to be called will this be called always ?

Comment: It is the only hook guaranteed before a `ContentProvider` `onCreate()` however, a better solution is to just create/build your dagger component in the `ContentProvider` `onCreate()` method and inject there..

Comment: Yes, I agree but in terms of overall design to support app dependencies and the content provider dependencies, I was planning to use dagger component dependency to achieve this, but that would still depend on my app's `oncreate` as thats where I setup my root component. Other approach was to use a totally separate component for CP, but then when my app is running I would have 2 instances of the service providers.

Comment: do you need those services to be accessed by any other components like your activities, other app's services / activities? if not, do you need them just to feed your custom `CP`?

Comment: Yes, I have for example CacheService which will be used for both App and CP, how can I solve for that ?

Comment: did you consider [sync adapters](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)?

Comment: Using sync adapters will still triggers my content provider at a scheduled time, even when my app is not running. I think the question comes back to same, can share a singleton view of my dependencies when using the app and when not using the app.